# Return Jira Issues by Epic Name

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to return all issues that have epics similar epics. For example, I would like to return all issues that have an epic that starts with "Wolf 2.0".

Currently, I have a filter that returns issues based on epicLink:

> project = "Wolf EMR" AND "Epic Link" in (WLF-216809, WLF-221642,
>   WLF-221783, WLF-221643, WLF-221644, WLF-221414, WLF-221645,
>   WLF-226267, WLF-215589, WLF-223041, WLF-226545, WLF-219544,
>   WLF-225148) AND Status != Done AND issuetype not in
>   subtaskIssueTypes() ORDER BY status DESC, Rank ASC

This is problematic as each time I create a new epic I have to update the list. I want to search instead on epic name so that I can find all similarly named epics. But when I use the following query it returns just the epics themselves, not the associated stories.

> project = "Wolf EMR" AND "Epic Name"  ~  "Wolf 2.0*" AND Status !=
>   Done AND issuetype not in subtaskIssueTypes() ORDER BY status DESC,
>   Rank

I also tried explicitly asking for stories but then it returns no results:

> project = "Wolf EMR" AND "Epic Name"  ~  "Wolf 2.0*" AND Status !=
>   Done AND issuetype =  story ORDER BY status DESC, Rank

I have searched the web extensively but all solutions reference using Epic Link as I have done in the first example. I'm not sure if I can use Epic Name and if that is the case it looks like a bug.

Comment: Are you searching for specific Epi Names? Or you want to grab all the stories that has epic link?

Comment: I want to return all the issues that belong to epics that have a common naming pattern. I don't want to use Epic Link as that requires I update the list of epics each time a new one is created.

Comment: Epic Name belongs to the Epic Issue, not the Linked Issue - only an Epic has an Epic Name. It is not possible to filter based on the Epic Name. ScriptRunner provides a custom Function that will allow you to filter based on the Epic Name